# When an arguments is missing in R, how to call another function to use its default argument?

Tags: r, ggplot2, arguments

I have a function with multiple optional arguments to modify a plot using ggplot2. If any of these argument is missing, I want to use theirs default values in ggplot2. If there is only one argument, this can be done like:

```
simple_plot <- function (color) {
   p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg))

   if(!missing(color))
   {
      p <- p + geom_point(col = color)
   } else {
      p <- p + geom_point()            # use its default if the argument is missing
   }
}
```

However, this is not a good solution when there are multiple arguments to modify the plot's point shape, fill, axis titles, breaks, limits, etc. Is there a better way?

[Edited to clarify my question]
Thanks for those who have responded to my questions. I would like to clarify my question by including the following codes. There will be more than one function to call and each function has multiple arguments. It doesn't seem using `do.call` is an easy way to implement.

```
better_plot <- function(col.y1, shape.y1, col.y2, shape.y2,
                        title.y1, breaks.y1, title.y2, breaks.y2, title){
  
  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) +

    # 1st y data points
    case_when(
      missing(col.y1) & missing(shape.y1) ~  geom_point(aes(y = mpg)),
      missing(col.y1) & !missing(shape.y1) ~  geom_point(aes(y = mpg), shape = shape.y1),
      !missing(col.y1) & missing(shape.y1) ~  geom_point(aes(y = mpg), col = col.y1),
      !missing(col.y1) & !missing(shape.y1) ~  geom_point(aes(y = mpg), col = col.y1, shape = shape.y1)
    ) +

    # 2nd y data points
    case_when(
      missing(col.y2) & missing(shape.y2) ~  geom_point(aes(y = hp)),
      missing(col.y2) & !missing(shape.y2) ~  geom_point(aes(y = hp), shape = shape.y2),
      !missing(col.y2) & missing(shape.y2) ~  geom_point(aes(y = hp), col = col.y2),
      !missing(col.y2) & !missing(shape.y2) ~  geom_point(aes(y = hp), col = col.y2, shape = shape.y2)
    ) +

    # y axises - labels and breaks
    case_when(
      !missing(title.y1) & !missing(breaks.y1) & !missing(title.y2) & !missing(breaks.y2) ~ 
        scale_y_continuous(
          name = title.y1, breaks = breaks.y1,
          sec.axis = sec_axis(name = title.y2, breaks = breaks.y2)),
      
      !missing(title.y1) & !missing(breaks.y1) & !missing(title.y2) & missing(breaks.y2) ~ 
        scale_y_continuous(
          name = title.y1, breaks = breaks.y1, 
          sec.axis = sec_axis(name = title.y2)),
      
      !missing(title.y1) & !missing(breaks.y1) & missing(title.y2) & missing(breaks.y2) ~ 
        scale_y_continuous(
          name = title.y1, breaks = breaks.y1),
      
      .... # the remaining combinations...
      
    )
  
  # add plot title if any
  if(!missing(title)) p <- p + ggtitle(title)

  return(p)
}
```

Comment: So you want the named arguments to be distributed to different functions such as `ggplot`, `geom_point`, `scale_x_continuous` etc?

Comment: Yes. For example, title.x and title.y for axis titles. If any of these arguments is missing, the axis title will then be assigned by ggplot2 which by default are the names of x and y variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`do.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html) to call a function with a list of arguments. So all you need to do is collect your arguments into a list, and omit the missing ones.

As long as your arguments have the same name as the ones in the corresponding ‘ggplot2’ function, a simple [`match.call()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.call.html) is all that’s required:

```
simple_plot = function (color, shape, fill) {
    args = as.list(match.call())[-1L]
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + do.call('geom_point', args, envir = parent.frame())
}
```

For more complex functionality (e.g. mismatching argument names) you can manipulate the list before passing it to `do.call`; you can also construct an unevaluated call using [`as.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/call.html) and evaluate it later:

```
the_call = as.call(c(as.name('geom_point'), args))
# … evaluate it:
eval.parent(the_call)
```

Note that `args` may contain *unevaluated expressions*, so the evaluation needs to happen in the calling environment (which is done in both cases above). If you want to inject your own names that are local to the function, you need to evaluate those before adding them, otherwise they won’t be found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added some codes to clarify my question. How about a nested function call like `scale_y_continuous(name = title.y1, breaks = breaks.y1, sec.axis = sec_axis(name = title.y2, breaks = breaks.y2))`?

Comment: @HiCLH Having nested calls doesn’t really change anything. In your code you’ll of course add some handling of the argument list since not all arguments are dispatched to the same function — so you need to split up the list according to its names. But apart from that, the same approach works.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a function without the arguments it will use the defaults, so one option, if you really want to have some of those arguments in your wrapper function, is to copy the defaults over, as new defaults.

You can extract the default values of a function using `formals()`, for example

```r
formals(ggplot2::geom_point)
#> $mapping
#> NULL
#> 
#> $data
#> NULL
#> 
#> $stat
#> [1] "identity"
#> 
#> $position
#> [1] "identity"
#> 
#> $...
#> 
#> 
#> $na.rm
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $show.legend
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $inherit.aes
#> [1] TRUE
```

Note that `col` isn't one of these; `col` is passed via `...` so that's even harder to deal with.

You can retrieve these defaults, but to loop over which of them are missing in your wrapper you want to use `missing()` and that has it's own complications... from `?missing`:

> Currently missing can only be used in the immediate body of the function that defines the argument, not in the body of a nested function or a local call. This may change in the future.

> This is a ‘special’ primitive function: **it must not evaluate its argument**.

(emphasis mine). You can't pass a symbol to `missing()`, it needs the character string, so you can't do something like `sapply(args, missing)`, it just doesn't work.

You can preserve the missingness, though, by not evaluating your own arguments if you don't need to. For example

```r
my_fun <- function(na.rm = formals(ggplot2::geom_point)[["na.rm"]], 
                   position = formals(ggplot2::geom_point)[["position"]], 
                   ...) {
  ggplot2::geom_point(na.rm = na.rm, position = position, ...)
}

my_fun(na.rm = TRUE, position = "jitter")
#> geom_point: na.rm = TRUE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = TRUE
#> position_jitter

my_fun(position = "jitter")
#> geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_jitter

my_fun(na.rm = TRUE)
#> geom_point: na.rm = TRUE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = TRUE
#> position_identity

all.equal(ggplot2::geom_point(), my_fun())
#> [1] TRUE
```

This will use the named arguments if you specify them (you can even change the name of them if you really want) and use the defaults otherwise. Note that I haven't wrapped *all* the defaults, just those I want to have in my function. You can still pass along additional arguments to `...` and otherwise take the default.

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars, ggplot2::aes(cyl, hp)) + my_fun(position = "jitter", col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>